# Random sampling of mutual relations between different theories

Tags: statistics, logic, random

Assume we have a generator of statements (black box type). We generated a long list of $N$ statements ($N \gg 1$).

For theory $T_1$, approximately $x_1N$ of the statements are true and $y_1N$ are false, $x_1+y_1=1$. Then there is another theory, $T_2$, and it is somehow correlated with theory $T_1$ such that, for $T_2$, the fraction of true and false statements are
\begin{equation}
x_2=\psi_{12}x_1+(1-\mu_{12})y_1,~~~
y_2=(1-\psi_{12})x_1+\mu_{12}y_1 
\end{equation}

Graphically the relation  between theories $T_1$ and $T_2$ can be represented as a point on the unit square. Note that the inverse relation, between $T_2$ and $T_1$ can be different, i.e., described with $\psi_{21}\neq \psi_{12}$ and $\mu_{21}\neq \mu_{12}$.

There are ultimate cases, e.g., $\psi_{12} = \mu_{12} = 1$ (all statements that are true/false for $T_1$ are true/false for $T_2$), or $\psi_{12} = \mu_{12} = 0$ (converse). There are cases when the theories are not correlated at all, $\psi_{12} = 1 - \mu_{12}$ (antidiagonal of the square).

Now I need to add a third theory, $T_3$ and define coefficients, $\psi_{13}, \psi_{31}, \mu_{13}, \mu_{31},..., \mu_{32}$, relating it to the already existing two theories.  But not all values  of the coefficients are legitimate because some of them can violate some common sense logics (these conditions I do not know how to formulate explicitly). For example, if $\psi_{12} = \mu_{12} = 1$
and $\psi_{31} = \mu_{32} = 1$, there is only one (probably) choice  $\psi_{32} = \mu_{32}=1$.

The question is how to sample for three theories a random set of coefficients $\psi_{ij}, \mu_{ij}$, $i,j = 1,2,3,~i \neq j$ without violating some basic principles (of common-sense logics?).  What conditions to fulfill? What is possible sampling algorithm(s)?
And,  finally, how to generalize this to the case of $n$ theories?

This set-up is not so specific that the problem should be considered in the framework of mathematical logics or model theory. One could think of $N$ pathogen cells and different drugs, $\{T_i\}$, $j=1,..,n$, so for drug $T_j$ on average $x_jN$ cells are sensitive  and $y_jN$ cells are resistant.

Answer (score 1):

This all becomes easier to handle if you consider the fractions $n_{t_1t_2t_3}$ of statements that have truth value $t_i$ in theory $i$. If you want, you can express all your coefficients in terms of these values. For instance,

$$\psi_{12}=\frac{n_{11}}{n_{11}+n_{10}}=\frac{n_{110}+n_{111}}{n_{110}+n_{111}+n_{100}+n_{101}}$$

(where the two-index values $n_{t_1t_2}=n_{t_1t_20}+n_{t_1t_21}$ sum over the third index). The only constraints imposed on these $8$ fractions are that they not be negative and sum to $1$, and your coefficients are admissible iff they can be represented by a valuation of these fractions that fulfils those constraints.

To sample, generate $7$ independent uniform random samples in the unit interval $[0,1]$ and use the $8$ interval lengths that these $7$ points cut the interval into as the $8$ fractions.

In the case of $n$ theories, there are $2^n$ fractions, and you can sample them by cutting the unit interval with $2^n-1$ random numbers.

Comment: Amazing, joriki! Perfect formalization - and the clear answer. Do you see any relation of this problem to something else (you know, have seen. etc)?  Is there any context? An yet another question - what if I want to control value s of $\psi$'s and $\mu$'s,  in order to enforce some correlations between theories? How should I modify the procedure to make the sampling of fractions conditioned on certain values of the coupling coefficients? It is, to some extent, an inverse problem.

Comment: @trurl: It reminds me of arguments in probability theory, where this sort of representation can be used to prove inequalities e.g. about conditional probabilities that look mysterious at first but follow if you look at which of these $2^n$ elementary subdivisions the probabilities are sums of.

Comment: @trurl: About the new question in your edit: It depends on what exactly you want to enforce. If you only have mild conditions on the $\psi$s and $\mu$s, rejection sampling might be efficient (sample uniformly and reject samples that don't satisfy the conditions). If that would be too wasteful, you might need to fulfil the conditions explicitly, but how to do that would depend on the conditions. Another option (a generalization of rejection sampling) is weighted sampling: Sample uniformly and weight the samples with some weighting function that reflects how well the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you, @joriki! To you it was perhaps a trivial exercise but I am still amazed by the clarity of your solution of the problem.

Comment: @trurl: You're welcome. I made a slight correction in the answer – of course the fractions must not be negative.